# Matching a closing brace in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a setting in Visual Studio 2008 that I can turn on which would generate a matching closing brace for a opening brace?

EDIT: I would imagine that an IDE as powerful as Visual Studio would have this very useful feature.

EDIT: Is there a macro that can be written? From the responses I have received it looks like [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) is the only option. I don't want to have to ask my company to invest in the ReSharper tool, I work for a rather large enterprise and getting anything approved from procurement is not an easy task.

EDIT: I am using VS 2010 Ultimate. The Power Tools and Power commands now do everything I was looking for in this post.

Comment: Believe it or not, automatic brace closing still doesn't come as standard in VS2008. Like Simon, I use ReSharper to get this functionality and a whole lot more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It does a whole lot more besides just the closing brace. The only downside is it's not free. But give it a try. The code analysis is worth the price anyway.

Comment: Maybe for earlier versions of VS. Since VS 2015 resharper is pretty useless and a productivity killer.

Answer (score 29):

> *I know the original question is about VS2008, but I'm putting this here as info for other people and to make it useful for recent versions*

### VS 2010 and VS 2012

The **Productivity Power Tools** (available for [VS2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) and [VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd)) extension now supports automatic brace completion.

If you already have it installed for VS2010, you must update to at least version 10.0.10710.22. Click

```
Tools -> Extension Manager -> Updates
```

Once you have it installed, you can turn brace completion on or off by going to

```
Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> All Extensions -> Automatic Brace Completion
```

> *The most recent version now provides the ability to turn of any features you don't like so you can configure it to your requirements*

### VS 2013

Even though there's a matching addin for Visual Studio 2013 as well, VS now has native support for automatic brace completion without using any addins. Just go to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C#
```

Tick checkbox against **Automatic brace completion**

Comment: I installed it the very day it was released :)

Comment: I think you mean: Tools->Options->Productivity power tools->All Extensions->Automatic Brace Completion.

Comment: Almost 2 years after you posted this it's still helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, you can use autocompletion and code snippets.

If you want to write a for loop, just type "for" and then TAB. VS will complete it (including the braces).

Same thing for if, struct, class, switch... You don't even have to type the first brace !!

Good paper about it here : https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=655

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: Thanks hyde, [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3288454/1123295) appears to be right: The Microsoft Productivity Power Tools do have a [2012 version](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) now.*

Original outdated answer:

It appears that the Microsoft Productivity Power Tools don't work in VS 2012 yet. If you're looking for a solution that works on the new version, you can check out this extension:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2013 there is the option of "Automatic delimiter highlighting" (under tools, options, text editor) and while checking  that box should highlight matching braces, it doesn't under default settings.  This is because the default background is white, and the default highlight color is also white.  This can be changed by going to environment, fonts and colors, and changing the background color of "brace matching (rectangle)".  Then matching braces will be highlighted and visible.

I realized after I answered that the question was creating the brace not being able to find existing braces. As that's the question I was trying to answer when I ended up here I'm leaving the answer in case it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are looking for VS does have some standard auto completion if[tab][tab] and for[tab][tab] try[tab][tab](and lots of other constructs) will get you more than the matching braces in a really nice fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but I guess you got use an independently running AutoHotKey script to insert closing brackets/quotes for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pay for ReSharper or a similar package, I made a free extension to automatically close braces.  You can find it in the Visual Studio Gallery at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/0e33cb22-d4ac-4f5a-902f-aff5177cc94d.  It will only work in Visual Studio 2010 though.