# AutoClose parens, braces, etc in Eclipse and in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, editor

I want to know the name of the specific editing mode in which the editor automatically closes the paren after you write **(**, and then you can jump right after the **)** when you press a tab. It does the same thing with **"**. How can one get this thing working in VisualStudio and in Eclipse?

Thanks.

**upd**: clarification of the title. The name of the feature is AutoClose

**upd2**: Visual Studio doesn't support this natively --> [source](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=383088)

**upd3**: A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448186/matching-a-closing-brace-in-visual-studio). Turns out ReSharper can do this for C# and VB, but still nothing for native C++.

Comment: Generally questions of type 'How do I do this in _A_ and _B_' should be split in two. I doubt there are unitary settings for Eclipse and VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going for the eclipse IDE (cause is the one that i know, but there are lots of VisualStudio gurus over here that probably will come with the other half).

In eclipse you are talking about the "Formatter" feature, that is located under the menu Window / Preferences, and then select in the right tab (Java / Code Style / Formatter ) and then you can edit the active profile (there is a section called "braces" that defines the behaviour that you are talking about).

To assign that behavior to another file type, you can choose open that file with the Java Editor, or assign that editor (Java Editor) by default to another extension (Under General / Editors / File Associations, also in the preferences dialog).

Hope this makes sense for you.

Comment: Thanks, too bad I can't upvote yet (<15), but I will when I can. :)

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense? If I understand you correctly